# Creating has_one association within the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

Let us consider the below model.

```
User{ id:number(primary_key), column1:string, column2:string)
```

Now, the column1 can be any string, but column2 can be either null, or have values from column1. However column1 and column2 can't be same. I.E. column2 will be the foreign key and it will reference column1.

How will i create a has_one relationship with these constraints.

Something like,

```
has_one :master_agreement, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'column2', :primary_key => 'column1'
```

but the above mentioned doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you need a foreign key value for a self-join, it would make more sense to reference the id of the table, wouldn't it?

Comment: actually this must work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup a self-joining relationship in rails you want to use `belongs_to` not `has_one` as the key difference is that `belongs_to` places the foreign key column on the model's table - while `has_one` places it on the other end.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company # references users.company_id
  has_one :company # references companies.user_id
end
```

Lets consider a system where you have a hierarchy of categories:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

This creates a self joining relationship with the `categories.parent_id` foreign key column which references `categories.id`.

While you could potentially use something different than `categories.id` as the reference you are just making things harder on yourself as the id column already is an indexed primary key column.